# Parallelize MSGARCH's function (FitML) on R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I'm using MSGARCH (R's packages) on windows 10

I should fitting any markov switching model many times (12.500 with a while and for loop) with this code

```
X = CreateSpec(variance.spec = list(model = c()), 
               distribution.spec = list(distribution = c()))

Y = FitML(data, spec = X)
```

How to parallelize the last function (FitML)?? I'd like to run many FitML() function for various X values

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for specific hints concerning R.

Comment: When you ask how to parallelize FitML function, do you mean running a single instance of this function in parallel (which is not possible) or running many FitML() function for various X values?

Comment: sorry for the mistake, thanks Katia for the support. I'd like to run many FitML() function for various X values.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have a list of `X`:s, let us call it `Xs`, then you can call `FitML()` on each of the elements as:

```
Ys <- lapply(Xs, FUN = FitML)
```

The above applies the function to the elements *sequentially*.  To do the same in parallel, you can use the [future.apply](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future.apply) package part of the [future](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future) ecosystem (I'm the author).  The following parallelizes on your local machine and works on all operating systems:

```
library(future.apply)
plan(multiprocess)

Ys <- future_lapply(Xs, FUN = FitML)
```

If there is a random-number-generation (RNG) component to `FitML()`, then you need to use:

```
Ys <- future_lapply(Xs, FUN = FitML, future.seed = TRUE)
```

to make sure you use proper random numbers.

If you don't specify `plan()`, or specify `plan(sequentially)`, it will run sequentially.